# SQL - count values by date

Tags: sql, date, count

I need an sql code editing. I need count of x and y values by month. How can i get that?

My code is

```
> SELECT DISTINCT TR_TYPE, ORDER_NO FROM INVENTORY WHERE TRANS_TYPE IN
> ('X', 'Y') AND CREATED_DATE BETWEEN '01-JUL-20' AND '01-DEC-20'
```

I want to see something like that:

```
Jul : 30
Aug : 60
..
Dec : 27
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Oracle. İm not good at sql. Sorry for my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I believe u can make a group by and count(*), something like that:

```
SELECT MONTH(TR_TYPE) AS m, count(*)
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE TR_TYPE>= '2020-07-01'
AND TR_TYPE<= '2020-08-01'
GROUP BY m
```

Comment: There is no "distinct", This isnt be a problem?

Comment: If u just add distinct its okay i believe

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `group by` and `count` as follows:

```
SELECT MONTH(TR_TYPE) AS month_, count(*) as cnt
  FROM INVENTORY
 WHERE TR_TYPE>= '2020-07-01'
   AND TR_TYPE<= '2020-08-01'
   AND TRANS_TYPE IN ('X', 'Y')
GROUP BY MONTH(TR_TYPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests that you are using Oracle.  In that database, I would recommend:

```
SELECT TRUNC(CREATED_DATE, 'MON') as month, COUNT(*) as cnt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRANS_TYPE = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as x_cnt,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRANS_TYPE = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as y_cnt
FROM INVENTORY
WHERE TRANS_TYPE IN ('X', 'Y') AND
      CREATED_DATE >= DATE '2020-07-01' AND
      CREATED_DATE < DATE '2020-12-01'
GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATED_DATE, 'MON')
ORDER BY month;
```

Notes:

- The date constants use the standard method for inserting a date constant.
- The date comparisons do not use `BETWEEN`.  That is misleading because `BETWEEN` includes *both* end points.  This version is more accurate and works whether or not the date has a time component.
- The `GROUP BY` key is the full date truncated to the beginning of the month.  This is much safer than extracting the month -- particularly if your date range exceeds one year.
- It also adds counts for "X" and "Y" separately.  Your question is a little unclear if you want this (the text suggests "yes" the sample results, "no").

Comment: It looks perfect but i wonder where is the "distinct" term. I dont want to count duplicated lines.

Comment: @sabredin . . . The `group by` takes care of that.